# Why I am seeing a user name with a yellow dot?

Tags: discussion, dupehammer

[image]

Why there's a yellow dot next to user name?

Reference link : [Uniquely identify IOS device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23947523/uniquely-identify-ios-device)

Comment: That's a very vague duplicate. Ofcourse, it explains what the close-vote superpowers are, but does that yellow dot only mean "close-vote" superpowers or does this user have more powers? Also do you get it with a certain amount of rep or do you need to cast flags or other things?

Comment: @Hugo That is all it means. You get close-vote powers by earning a gold badge in the topic. All of those things are explained in the linked question.

Comment: @Hemang: To put it short, normally it does take several user to close a question. Under certain conditions (gold tag badge for this tag) a user can do it alone, and Noah Witherspoon is one of this cases.

Comment: Dude, _tooltips_!